# Is there any shorcut for the ''PS Button'' on Ps3, using a Ps1/Ps2 Controller?

Tags: ps3, controllers, backwards-compatibility

I got the first three Sony consoles (and the PSP too) the thing is, i like to use my old PS1 controller (the analog one) on my Ps2 and Ps3, everything works fine, but the only thing i'm missing, at least on the Ps3, is the PS button on the middle, i don't have problems since i can press the button on the Ps3 controller, but does the Ps1/Ps2 controller have maybe a combination of buttons in order to enter on this menu?

Thanks in regard.

Comment: Try updating your firmware, the Analog button in the middle of the controller should do the trick. (Source [PSU Forum](http://www.psu.com/forums/showthread.php/102795-PS2-Controller-on-PS3-PS-Button)). If it's true I'll add it as answer.

Comment: Hmm, i got my Ps3 at the latest firmware, but i'll try, for now when i press the Analog button the only thing it does is to play the game, i can't play without the Analog button working, but if i press it again maybe the menu will appear. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it, i got the latest firmware and i pressed the button but nothing happens, it just turns off the analog function.

Comment: Bummer! Let me search something else...

Comment: It seems that "You need an adapter to use a ps2 dualshock controller on the ps3, and usually the adapter has a ps button on it" ([source](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/tech-centre/88309-ps-button-ps2-controller.html))

Comment: Some say to press Analog twice or keep Select pressed for a couple of seconds, but I doubt this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to get to that menu with a Dualshock 1 or 2 Controller, I've already tried everything a few years back.